# validate_required does not set changeset as invalid if field missing

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a changeset called by an update (PUT) method in a phoenix application. The `validate_required` function is not working as I expect it to. If no values are sent in the PUT request the changeset is still marked as valid. If I inspect `changeset.changes` I get the value `%{}`.

```
def rsvp_changeset(guest, attrs) do
  guest
  |> cast(attrs, [:attending, :comment, :some_optional_value])
  |> validate_required(:attending, message: "Please state if attending")
  |> validate_required(:comment, message: "Please enter comment")
end
```

Is my understanding of what `validate_required` is meant to do wrong and if so how can I ensure that the request contains values for the fields I want changed?

Comment: Does `guest` already have the fields set? `validate_required` only makes sure the values are set and not whitespace-only strings, not that they were changed. So if `guest` already has them set it'll pass as long as you aren't unsetting them.

Comment: Removing default values worked. Had to update the schema and migrate the DB to allow nulls

Comment: You could still disallow nulls but not provide a default value